# Django 'File' object has no attribute 'content_type'

Tags: python, django, thumbnails, content-type

I am defining a function to create a thumbnail for each image uploaded in the model.
Below is my code:

```
def create_thumbnail(self):
     if not self.coverphoto:
         return

     from PIL import Image
     from cStringIO import StringIO
     from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
     import os

     # Set our max thumbnail size in a tuple (max width, max height)
     THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (200,200)

     DJANGO_TYPE = self.coverphoto.file.content_type

     if DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/jpeg':
         PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
         FILE_EXTENSION = 'jpg'
     elif DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/png':
         PIL_TYPE = 'png'
         FILE_EXTENSION = 'png'
     elif DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/gif':
         PIL_TYPE = 'gif'
         FILE_EXTENSION = 'gif'

     # Open original photo which we want to thumbnail using PIL's Image
     image = Image.open(StringIO(self.coverphoto.read()))

     image.thumbnail(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)

     # Save the thumbnail
     temp_handle = StringIO()
     image.save(temp_handle, PIL_TYPE)
     temp_handle.seek(0)

     # Save image to a SimpleUploadedFile which can be saved into
     # ImageField
     suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(self.coverphoto.name)[-1],
             temp_handle.read(), content_type=DJANGO_TYPE)
     # Save SimpleUploadedFile into image field
     self.coverphoto_thumbnail.save('%s_thumbnail.%s'%(os.path.splitext(suf.name)[0],FILE_EXTENSION), suf,save=False)
```

When I run the unit test, it show error:

```
'File' object has no attribute 'content_type'
```

And the indicated error line is:

```
DJANGO_TYPE = self.coverphoto.file.content_type
```

Since I get this block of code from an old django snippet. I think this might be caused by different django version.

May I know how can I check content_type in the Django 1.6?

Is there a good way to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
    from mimetypes import MimeTypes
    import urllib
    mime = MimeTypes()
    url = urllib.pathname2url(file_name)
    mime_type = mime.guess_type(url)
```

Comment: OK but what to do with `mime_type` now?

Comment: @alexislg - you can use it to set the content_type instead of `DJANGO_TYPE` from above code

Comment: thanks, but it is too complicated for nothing, here is a simpler way : 
`from mimetypes import guess_type`
`guess_type(file_name)`

Comment: @amdan - Thanks, but I had answered for Python 2.7, there was no easy way that time to guess the mime type. Python3.4+ versions have got many exceptional features later.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it the following way:

```
...
#DJANGO_TYPE = self.image.file.content_type

if self.image.name.endswith(".jpg"):
    PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
    FILE_EXTENSION = 'jpg'
    DJANGO_TYPE = 'image/jpeg'

elif self.image.name.endswith(".png"):
    PIL_TYPE = 'png'
    FILE_EXTENSION = 'png'
    DJANGO_TYPE = 'image/png'
...
```

Works for me. Instead of looking for the conten_type, you just look at the file ending. If you need .gif or others, you need to lookup the correct content types and add other `self.image.name.endswith(".gif")` and so forth.