# Django instantiate a file field using model form

Tags: python, django

I am unable to instantiate the pdf file field from the model form. The field is validated to only allow pdf files. Works well but an error occurs when saving instantiated form that has not been edited.

***validators.py***

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validateA(value):
    if value.file.content_type != 'application/pdf':
        raise ValidationError(u'upload a pdf file')
```

***model.py***

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    image_fileA = ResizedImageField()
    pdf_fileB = models.FileField(validators=[validateA])
    pdf_fileC = models.FileField(validators=[validateA])
```

***forms.py***

```
class FormA(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = modelA
        fields = ['image_fileA', 'pdf_fileB', 'pdf_fileC']
        widgets = {
            'image_fileA': forms.FileInput(),
            'pdf_fileB': forms.FileInput(),
            'pdf_fileC': forms.FileInput(),
        }
```

***views.py***

```
def viewA(request, pk):
    template = 'app/edit.html'
    a = modelA.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = FormA(instance=a)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormA(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=a)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('page')
    context = {'a': a, 'form': form, }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

***edit.html***

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {%if a.image_fileA%}
    <img src="{{a.image_fileA.url}}">
    {{form.group_logo}}
    {%else%}Not Available{%endif%}

    {% if a.pdf_fileB%}
    <a href="{{a.pdf_fileB.url}}"></a>
    {{form.pdf_fileB}}
    {%else%}Not Available{%endif%}

    {% if a.pdf_fileC%}
    <a href="{{a.pdf_fileC.url}}"></a>
    {{form.pdf_fileC}}

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

***What I have tried***

I had to use if else to enable file upload in case the file was not available. Have also attached a URL link to enable one to see uploaded files.

***Errors***

I expect all fields to have form instances but when I try to save the form without editing I get the following error ***'File' object has no attribute 'content_type'***

Hence the form is only saved when all fields are edited.

Can somebody guide me on where am doing it wrongly?

***Expectattions***

When on the editing page, one should be able to see all data attached to respective fields.

Editing or not editing the form should save successfully without errors

Validation should be used to check if file uploaded or files already uploaded are pdf files

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397637/django-file-object-has-no-attribute-content-type

Comment: @shafik I was unable to implement it earlier on, could you guide me if you understood the solution provided from the shared link?

Comment: @shafik I have added validators.py files. When commented the error goes away. I need it working using validators.py. I guess validation is what is causing the error. How can I resolve it so that there is no need to check the already uploaded pdf files again?

Comment: can u debug at this point `if value.file`. The file objects don't have `content_type`. You need to split the file name to get the file extensions.